# robot understand human language

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any packages or tutorials about that robot understanding what I’m saying.while I’m not talking about speech recognition or voice recognition. I`m talking about robot understanding human words.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215096/robot-understand-human-language/) by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2015-08-02**:
Isn't that speech recognition:) ? Or you wanted to learn about natural language processing?

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2015-08-03**:
i wanna know if someone has already embedded natural language processing in some package,so that we can use these package directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a wrapper for the voice recognition phinx: http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx
and Google Speech http://wiki.ros.org/gspeech and another one here: http://rospeex.org/top/

---

Update:
So you need a chat bot, I guess:
https://github.com/jstnhuang/chatbot

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2015-08-03**:
you missed my point.im not looking for voice recognition.im asking how a robot understand human language.when i ask him"whats ur name?"his answer would be like"my name is...",not"its sunny today."how would he understand they two should have a similor or same answer.

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2015-08-03**:
i help others ask this question, and thank you to answer me, cyborg

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-08-03**:
See Update.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Robbie the robot uses a android phone for voice recognition and a node to send the text to a chatbot or control the robot with a NLTK
here is a link to the repo https://github.com/inmoov-ros/inmoov_ros

more info can be found at http://escaliente-robotics.blogspot.com.au/

---

Originally posted by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) with karma: 215 on 2015-08-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2